# Specflow - Close browser after all tests are done

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

I want to execute two test one by one, following feature examples.
It work but i don't know how to close browser when second test is done.

I've tried AfterFeature hook but it didnt work. I am just stuck logged in. I want to close browser in this moment

Here is the code

```
public class LoginSteps
    {
        [BeforeScenario("LoginProperly")]
        public static void BeforeScenario()
        {
            Browser.Initialize();
        }

        [AfterScenario("LoginProperly")]
        public static void AfterScenario()
        {

            Browser.ClearCache();
        }

        [AfterFeature("LoginProperly")]
        public static void AfterFeature()
        {
          Browser.Quit();

        }


        [Given(@"I navigate to login page")]
        public void GivenINavigateToLoginPage()
        {
            Browser.Wait();
            Pages.Navigation.GoToSignIn();

        }

        [Given(@"I have completed the form with '(.*)' and '(.*)'")]
        public void GivenIHaveCompletedTheFormWithAnd(string email, string password)
        {
            Pages.Login.LogIn(email, password);
        }

        [When(@"I press Submit")]
        public void WhenIPressSubmit()
        {
            Pages.Login.ClickLogin();
        }

        [Then(@"I should see my account panel")]
        public void ThenIShouldSeeMyAccountPanel()
        {
            Pages.Account.IsAt();
        }
    }
}
```

> Feature file

```
Feature: Login
    In order to use my account
    As an application user
    I want to be able to log in and log out

@LoginProperly
Scenario Outline: Login with correct Email adress and Password
    Given I navigate to login page
    And I have completed the form with '<email>' and '<password>'
    When I press Submit
    Then I should see my account panel

    Examples: 

    |     email         |  password  |
    | tescik@gmail.com  |   11111    |
    | tescik2@gmail.com |   22222    |
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `[AfterTestRun]`

```
    [AfterTestRun]
    public static void AfterWebFeature()
    {
        Browser.Quit();
        Brrowser.Dispose();
    }
```

I always call dispose after I call quit on the IWebDriver.

Answer (score -5):

Get the browser process and then kill it.  Add this code to your exit method of test case.

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("your browser name", "your pc name").First().Kill();
```

Comment: Selenium webdriver has the capacity to close down the browser.  the OP should not have to resort to killing processes externally for it to work.